# Is it possible to add afield in wireless trace format in ns2?

Tags: c++, networking, ns2, energy

Actually, I want to add some functions into the energy model...
I added functions in the class **energy-model.h** as

```
"inline double erel()"
"virtual void NodeReliab(...)" and a variable "double erel_;"
```

then declared the functions in the **energy-model.cc**.
Afterthat, I changed a line in the **cmu-trace.cc file to include erel() value** in trace format as,

```c++
sprintf(pt_->buffer() + offset,
    "[hi: energy %f ei %.3f es %.3f et %.3f **erel %.3f** er %.3f] ",
    thisnode->energy_model()->energy(),
    thisnode->energy_model()->ei(),
    dthisnode->energy_model()->es(),
    thisnode->energy_model()->et(),
    thisnode->energy_model()->erel(), // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    thisnode->energy_model()->er());
```

after executing make it does not display erel value in the trace file, it displays as usual. However, there is no error in make.
How can I add a variable in the trace format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

successfully added a field in the wireless trace file format. 
After modification/addition of methods, classes, files, functions .... etc. 
the make should be executed as,

```
$ make clean
$ make 
$ make install
```

then, it compiles all modified/added values/fns for ns2.35.